# C-x C-f Problem:

Tags: find-file, ido-find-file, treemacs

When i want to create a new file with `C-x C-f` (`ido-find-file`), and type `main.lua`, Emacs does not create a new file in the current directory (`default-directory`).  Instead, it visits an existing `main.lua` which is in another directory.

Similarly when I want to create a new directory `src`, instead of creating a new directory Emacs visits a `src` directory in another project.

This means I can never create a new file or a new directory.

I've installed the package `tree-emacs`. I have the same problem when I right-click a tree-emacs buffer and try to create a new file or a new directory - Emacs visits an existing file or directory which I do not want.

How can I stop Emacs from looking outside the current directory for an existing file or dir, instead of creating a buffer for a new one in the current directory?

Comment: To which command is your `C-x C-f` bound? You can tell it with `C-h k C-x C-f`.

Comment: "C-x C-f runs the command ido-find-file, which is an interactive
autoloaded compiled Lisp function in ‘ido.el’.

It is bound to <open>, C-x C-f, <menu-bar> <file> <new-file>.

(ido-find-file)"

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Ido, you can hit `C-f` whenever you want to fall back to regular `find-file`, thus preventing Ido from doing fancy things. If you want to disable the feature that lets Ido retrieve files from subdirectories for good, add

```lisp
(setq ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length -1)
```

to your init file. Then you can always use `M-s` to invoke it manually.

Comment: it works thanks a lot.

Comment: Or you could disable `ido-find-file` completely but continue to use `ido`: `(define-key (cdr ido-minor-mode-map-entry) [remap find-file] nil)`

Comment: @olegharput: if the answer works for you, please [accept it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I was about to say that. I guessed that some completion package might be interfering.

Comment: If this answers the question, you might want to *accept* this answer. (Or you might want to wait a while, to see if you get another answer that you prefer.)